# Insulating a communications panel from attic heat

Tags: insulation, subpanel, attic-door

I have a security system/cable tv coax/phone/LAN distribution panel in a closet off an upstairs hallway whose back is open to my attic.  I have never really worried about the heat that comes through all the holes in the back of the panel, but we have just converted to fiber optic from cable and this closet is where they put the combination modem router, so I would prefer to keep it cooler.  Looking for recommendations for the back of the panel.  I am planning to put some foam board on the door. Would that be preferred for the panel or just staple some conventional kraft faced insulation over it? Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Attic side:
[image]

Closet side:
[image]

Comment: 'Attic heat'? Are you taking about the unconverted space, or the decorated space in the background? What temperatures does it reach in these spaces? Generally, the whole idea with 'server racks' is you need to keep cool air moving over them, venting out & away from them, not wrapping them up tight in their own generated heat.

Comment: Could you take & post a picture of the closet side of the installation, with the closet door open?

Comment: I have edited my question to include the requested pictures...  The new modem is on the shelf to the upper left of the door.  It opens into the closet, but the rear of the panel gets hot attic air through the mounting holes in the rear of the panel.  Latitude is N 31 degrees.  Gets about 140 degrees in the summer in the attic.

Comment: Thanks for the new info.  Your setup is what I was suggesting in my answer.  I would go ahead and do what you were asking about - insulate the back wall of that cubby, the wall with the holes in it to keep the hot (in the summer) attic air away from your gear and the rest of the house.  I like foam board for these kinds of uses.

Answer (score 3):

I would move the panel, or at least the active components in it, out of the attic and into the conditioned space of your house.

Just putting insulation around a closed box with heat generating equipment in it is not going to help with the longevity of the equipment.  Even a small amount of heat generated in a well insulated box is going to raise the internal temperature.  FYI - my attic, in the Mid Atlantic, got to a temperature of 123 deg F  (~50.5 C) during the past summer.

Going along with what I said in my first paragraph, I think you should reverse the equipment box, so that you access it from the conditioned side of that wall.  Close off the attic side and cut an access panel on the interior side of the wall that will allow you to get to the equipment and wiring.  Then you can thoroughly insulate the back side of the box (I would use foam board insulation myself) to your heart's content.

Comment: Plain steel box, plain steel door, it's not well-insulated on the room side of things (probably even has ventilation slots, or doesn't fit tightly enough to need them...) Also not clear that the modem is in the panel, question says it's in the closet (that the panel opens into) You are already lookingat the back-side of the panel, so it does not need to be flipped.

Comment: "...modem is in the closet".  That would make things better, if the only thing in that panel in the attic is just passive wiring.

Comment: I'm confused by your recommendation. By all appearances, access to the panel _is_ from the conditioned side. That seemed reasonably obvious even with only the original picture that showed the attic side - that doesn't _look_ like the access side (other than random wires hanging out).

Comment: @Freeman - You're right.  It wasn't clear, at least to me what was on the closet side of the panel.  OP's second picture made that clear.  See my second comment under OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

First, fix the gaps in the insulation above and below the panel that are evident. After that, either type of insulation will work to block direct heat (and cold) from the attic space into the panel. It would appear you should also address the insulation situation in the stud bay beside the panel, which appears to be throughly trashed.

Comment: Yes, we have had numerous occasions of flying squirrels in our attic over the years.  Got a new roof last year and they failed to make it suitabily tight where the dormer soffit joins the adjacent roof.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you insulate the attic side of the cabinet to protect it from the summer heat.

**However**, insulating this will, potentially, cook your equipment inside the cabinet. To that end, you'll want to be sure to provide *good* airflow on the conditioned side of the panel.

We can't tell what the door looks like, but it is probably a solid metal panel. If it were mine, I'd take the door off, and drill several holes near the bottom (or a slot - depends on what tools you have access to), then do the same at the top. This will allow *cooler*, conditioned house air access to enter at the bottom and hotter air to flow out the top.

With these holes/slots created, it would be worth keeping an eye on temps inside the cabinet. If they're high (i.e. outside, or even at the upper end of, the manufacturer's specified working range - check the specs on *all* the equipment in there), you may need *more* cooling vents or a switch to active ventilation.

For active ventilation, PC cooling fans can be had very cheaply, even more cheaply if you don't mind the fan noise. You can plug one into a 5v or 12v power supply (I actually used an old PC PSU I had laying about). Mount the fan to the door at the top, blowing out (obviously, make a hole for the fan to push air through), and plug it in. This should provide enough air flow (drawing conditioned air in, pushing hot air out) to keep the temps reasonable.

You may want to also install a fan protective grill, especially if you have curious little fingers or long wet noses running around the house. Though, to be honest, a PC cooling fan will stop quite quickly if you stick your finger in it and doesn't really hurt much, if at all. Lungs attached to curious little fingers will likely let out a wail but there won't be any significant damage. The critters attached to the long, wet noses may also make a noise, but will learn very quickly that this is a thing not to be sniffed again. Fan protection is up to you...